# PHP's DateTime::format('U') returns timestamp from now, not from specified date?

Tags: php, datetime, format, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a DateTime object, initialized with a specific date:

```
$inputString = '06102013';
$myDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('mdY', $inputString);
```

Now I want to give it out in different Formats, using

```
$myFormat = 'd.m.Y';
$myDate->format($myFormat);
```

This works perfectly fine for all formats up until the point where I say:

```
$myFormat = 'U';
```

Then `$myDate->format('U');` contains just the *current* timestamp (the actual time when the function is called). But how do I get the timestamp from the original input date, `$inputString` in my case?

If this is important: I'm using PHP 5.3, but plan on upgrading soon.

Edit: Forgot to mention that

```
$myDate->getTimestamp();
```

also returns the time of calling, not the original time that the `DateTime` object was created with!

Comment: Please give a concrete example which we can run ourselves with all values filled in. We cannot reproduce this problem from the disjointed snippets you're showing.

Comment: @deceze I added some real values for testing.

Comment: I can't really reproduce what you describe: http://3v4l.org/2Or6T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *hours, minutes, seconds* part of the timestamp will refer to the current time, yes, because your input timestamp does not contain this information. PHP fills in the blanks from the current time at the point of instantiation. However, the day, month and year part of the timestamp represent your input in any version of PHP I tested (see http://3v4l.org/2Or6T).

Comment: Ah, yeah, I should have be more careful to the sub-day times... Thanks for claering that up.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php - just put an exclamation mark in your initial format